# how to use not null condition in YII2

Tags: php, yii2

Hi i want to use not null condition in my yii2 query how should i use that.
i don't want city and state null.

My query is

```
$query = new Query;             
      $query->select('ID, City,State,StudentName')                                  
                                ->from('student')                               
                                ->where(['IsActive' => 1])                                                                                                          
                                ->orderBy(['rand()' => SORT_DESC])
                                ->limit(10);                                
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => false,
       ]);
```

Comment: Which of the fields should not be null?

Comment: i don't want city and state null.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use the `not` operator combined with the fields that should not be null to generate a `IS NOT NULL` SQL statement. Like this:

```
$query = new Query;             
$query->select('ID, City,State,StudentName')
      ->from('student')                               
      ->where(['IsActive' => 1])
      ->andWhere(['not', ['City' => null]])
      ->andWhere(['not', ['State' => null]])
      ->orderBy(['rand()' => SORT_DESC])
      ->limit(10);
```

Also check the examples in the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where()-detail).

Comment: That does not generate "IS NOT NULL", that generates "NOT (City IS NULL)". @mariovials answer is the correct one here.

Answer (score 38):

```
->where(['IS NOT', 'column', null]);
```

get

`WHERE column IS NOT NULL`

You can also use, it is faster to type

```
->where('column IS NOT NULL')
```

In complex query

```
->where(['AND',
  'column1 IS NOT NULL', // works
  ['IS NOT', 'column2', null], // works
  ['column3' => $value],
)
```

Answer (score 13):

One of the options will be:

```
$query = new Query;             
$query->select('ID, City,State,StudentName')
    ->from('student')
    ->where(['IsActive' => 1])
    ->andWhere(['<>', 'City', null])
    ->andWhere(['<>', 'State', null])
    ->orderBy(['rand()' => SORT_DESC])
    ->limit(10);
```

Check official docs for [where](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail).

Comment: You have missing "," after the '<>'

Comment: @llioor Thanks, fixed. BTW, you can suggest edit too.

Comment: I can't because it is only 1 char to change. TW you forgot "," in the previous row as well.

Comment: This query is wrong. In SQL, you cannot use the comparison operators to compare NULL values. The proper way is to use "IS NULL" or "IS NOT NULL" conditions.

Answer (score 7):

```
    $items = BadOffer::find()->where(['OR',
                                               ['IS', 'moderator_id', (new Expression('Null'))],
                                               ['moderator_id' => $user->id],
    ]);
```

Answer (score 5):

In Yii2, we can use any of the queries below to verify the null condition,

```
->andWhere(['NOT', ['city' => null]]);
```

or

```
->andWhere(['<>', ['city' => null]]);
```

or

```
->andWhere('city IS NOT NULL');
```

Answer (score 4):

use `->andWhere(['not', ['State' => null]])` or `->andWhere(['is not', 'State', null]);`

Do no use :

1. `andFilterWhere`, as the `null` will make this filter be ignored
2. `->andWhere(['<>', 'State', null])` as it form query `AND State <> null`

Answer (score 3):

How to select non-empty columns in MySQL?

use **LENGTH** :

```
SELECT col1
FROM table
WHERE LENGTH(col1) > 0
```

Yii2 :

```
->andWhere(['>', 'LENGTH(col1)', 0])
```

Answer (score -3):

This work for me, but only when pass null as string

```
->andFilterWhere(['<>', '`city`', 'null']);
```

Comment: This may work only by accident - it create condition like `city <> 'null'`which may ignore null values (although it may depend on DBMS) but will also ignore fields with value `null` as string.